# Joint Entropy Performance in Julia

Tags: performance, julia, entropy

I wrote a function to calculate the joint entropy of each column pair in a matrix. But I would like to increase the performance regarding time and memory.

The function looks like this:

```
function jointentropy(aln)
  mat = Array(Float64,size(aln,2),size(aln,2))

  for i in combinations(1:size(aln,2),2)
    a = i[1]
    b = i[2]
    mina, maxa = extrema(aln[:,a])
    minb, maxb = extrema(aln[:,b])
    h = Array(Float64,(maxa-mina+1,maxb-minb+1))
    h = hist2d([aln[:,a] aln[:,b]],mina-1:1:maxa,minb-1:1:maxb)[3]
    h = h/size(aln[:,1],1)
    I,J,V = findnz(h)
    l = sparse(I,J,log2(V),maxa-mina+1,maxb-minb+1)
    mat[b,a] = - sum(l.*h)
  end
  return mat
end
```

Matrices that go into this function look like this:

```
rand(45:122,rand(1:2000),rand(1:2000))
```

An example with a 500x500 matrix resulted in the following @time output:

```
elapsed time: 33.692081413 seconds (33938843192 bytes allocated, 36.42% gc time)
```

...which seems to be a whole lot of memory...

Any suggestions on how to speed up this function and reduce memory allocation?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few ideas to speed up your function.

- If the range of all the columns is roughly the same, you can move the extrema computations outside the loop and reuse the same `h` array.
- `hist2d` creates a new array: you can use `hist2d!` to reuse the previous one.
- The assignment `h = h/size(aln[:,1],1)` creates a new array.
- The division in `h = h/size(aln[:,1],1)` is done for all the elements of the array, including the zeroes.
- You can use a loop instead of `findnz` and a sparse matrix (`findnz` already contains a loop).

.

```
function jointentropy2(aln)
  n1 = size(aln,1)
  n2 = size(aln,2)
  mat = Array(Float64,n2,n2) 

  lower, upper = extrema(aln)
  m = upper-lower+1
  h = Array(Float64,(m,m))
  for a in 1:n2
    for b in (a+1):n2
      Base.hist2d!(h,[aln[:,a] aln[:,b]],lower-1:1:upper,lower-1:1:upper)[3]
      s = 0
      for i in 1:m
        for j in 1:m
          if h[i,j] != 0
            p = h[i,j]  / n1
            s += p * log2(p)
          end
        end
      end
      mat[b,a] = - s
    end
  end
  return mat
end
```

This is twice as fast as the initial function,
and the memory allocations were divided by 4.

```
aln = rand(45:122,500,400)

@time x = jointentropy(aln)
# elapsed time: 26.946314168 seconds (21697858752 bytes allocated, 29.97% gc time)

@time y = jointentropy2(aln)
# elapsed time: 13.626282821 seconds (5087119968 bytes allocated, 16.21% gc time)

x - y  # approximately zero (at least below the diagonal -- 
       # the matrix was not initialized above it)
```

The next candidate for optimization is `hist2d` (here, you could use a loop and a sparse matrix).

```
@profile jointentropy2(aln)
Profile.print()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Especially the rebuilding of hist2d did save a lot of time. 
for the 500x400 matrix that is: `elapsed time: 1.766426231 seconds (1328912 bytes allocated)`. Pretty impressive speed gain... This is even four times faster than a similar function in R, written in c++...